# AWS ElasticBeanstalk Tomcat 8 - url redirect

Tags: redirect, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I test my java app on AWS ElasticBeanstalk single instance Tomcat8 (without load balancer).

I would like to use rewrite (redirect) rules (urls without www to urls with www etc).

How I can do this (where I can set rewrite rules)?